# need to sync onLocationChanged

Tags: android, google-maps, android-service, android-location

i am creating one application which broadcast the location of a user over a web for that i have created a service in which i am using `LocationListener` and getting updates from 
`onLocationChanged`

i have set `requestLocationUpdates` as follows

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                                15000,
                                                0, 
                                                geoHandler);
```

when ever i am getting an update in `onLocationChanged` i broadcast the location over web.

Now the problem is `onLocationChanged` gets fired too frequently even if it doesn't cross the time limit *(that is totally unpredictable)*  and which in turns trigger my custom function which is broadcasting the location information too frequently.

so i dont know how would i **sync** this process in a proper timely manner like after every 15 seconds the location will be broadcasted over web ,rather then firing it up too frequently

Comment: How about using an `Alarm` that repeats every 15 seconds. Then starting your `Service` you can check if location is changed and broadcast the location if necessary. This seems to be a basic approach. I may be missing something in your question.

Comment: @KerimOguzcanYenidunya this is a very bad approach. You consume power and battery for nothing.

Comment: @Hunt please check your code, because I just tested the same aproach as you did, and it works just fine.

Comment: @Tudor Did u try it with service ?

Comment: @Hunt yes, but with a bigger time interval.

Answer (score 1):

How frequent is the `onLocationChanged` being called?

It is an odd behabiour because when you add a minTime!=0 parameter to :

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, geoHandler)`

then the listener is not notified only after minTime.

After a deeper research I found that minTime is relative. It depends on many factors and therefore your onLocationChanged is not called precisely after minTime. Google recommands to use this parameter for power and battery efficiency. So you should use is as a bigger value, like 1000*60*5 (5 minutes.)

If you really need to broadcast your location on each 15 seconds you should bare in mind that GPS pinpoints can not be triggered instantly, it take at least 5-10 seconds (best case). Therefore you have to change your design to something like this:

- `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
  0, 0, geoHandler)`
- in `onLocationChanged` just check when was the last time you sent/processed your location, and if the time elapsed is >= 15 sec, broadcast it;

Hope it helps you.

Comment: sometimes its getting called every second and sometimes after every 5 seconds so its totally unpredictable.

Comment: @Hunt did you increase the value of minDistance?

Comment: Nope its zero , is there any standard value ?

Comment: You are giving minTime 15 seconds but since minDistance is 0 its considered as an update too frequently. You need to set some value that you think its not a considerable change in gps value.

Comment: @KerimOguzcanYenidunya If minTime=15sec and minDistance=1meter then both flags have to be true in order for the call to be made. Time and distance have to be both >= than minTime and minDistance.

Comment: I tried your approach but the issue is `onLocationChanged` it self is getting called haphazardly after setting 0 to time and distance so if the seconds gets passed inside `onLocationChanged` function broadcast wont get fired

Answer (score 1):

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)`

`minTime`   is minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds

`minDistance`   is minimum distance between location updates, in meters

You are setting minTime as 15seconds but since your minDistance is 0 meters its triggered too frequently. It doesnt have to wait for 15 seconds to pass since a slight change in GPS value triggers a location update. Giving some meters (e.g. 1 or 3) shall increase the interval between updates.

Comment: I tried to set it to 1 and yes its true its firing up less frequently but as both the conditions have to be satisfied so 15 sec interval not working